# Signing and notarizing install4j macOs dmg

Tags: macos, code-signing, install4j, code-signing-certificate, notarize

I have an apple developer id and I have a macOs app built using install4j. I need to codesign and notarize my app. I am using install4j UI to codesign and notarize. Notarization is failing with below logs

```
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "87565dea-7386-4b56-a708-c6ea740e9c61",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg",
  "uploadDate": "2021-07-27T16:27:26Z",
  "sha256": "138085690c790dc492d65a35369e8ee98efa6a604c4cb9fa8a6b4c47227bc9f5",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/wrapper-macosx-universal-32",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "i386"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/wrapper-macosx-universal-32",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "i386"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/wrapper-macosx-universal-32",
      "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "i386"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/wrapper-macosx-universal-64",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/wrapper-macosx-universal-64",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/wrapper-macosx-universal-64",
      "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/macos/wrapper",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/macos/wrapper",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/tanuki/macos/wrapper",
      "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/user/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.46.Final-osx-x86_64.jar/META-INF/native/libnetty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64.jnilib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "macos_20_1-SNAPSHOT.dmg/Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/user/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.46.Final-osx-x86_64.jar/META-INF/native/libnetty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64.jnilib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notarization also requires that binaries that are contained in JAR files to be signed. The install4j signing process does not scan for executables in JAR files automatically, you have to tell install4j what JAR files to scan by configuring the "JAR files to be scanned for binaries" setting on the "General Settings->Code signing" step. This is a starts-with comparison, so you add "netty-transport-" as a filter.

Also, you have to add the names of the executables of the Tanuki wrapper in the "Additional binaries to be signed", so "wrapper-macosx-universal-64", "wrapper-macosx-universal-32" and "wrapper".